# Delayed Ping of a link-local address with Windows 7/Server 2008 R2/Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-7, ipv6, ping, link-local

I have a strange effect here, which I do not understand.

```
PS C:\Users\user1> ping fe80::219:bbff:fe0e:c600%16  -t

Ping wird ausgeführt für fe80::219:bbff:fe0e:c600%16 mit 32 Bytes Daten:
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar. (Destination is unreachable)
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
.
.
.
Antwort von fe80::219:bbff:fe0e:c600%16: Zeit=1ms
Antwort von fe80::219:bbff:fe0e:c600%16: Zeit<1ms
Antwort von fe80::219:bbff:fe0e:c600%16: Zeit<1ms
.
.
```

As you can see the host (my default gateway) is not reachable for a while (1 or 2 minutes) and then it changes. I have this effect only with Windows 7 (Server 2008 R2, Server 2012 R2).

When I do a ping with a Linux-System (e.g. SLES12) or even with Windows XP the gateway is reachable immediately! So i think my config can't be so wrong.

Neighbor Discovery gives me:

```
netsh interface ipv6>show neighbors interface=16

Schnittstelle 16: LAN-Verbindung 2


Internetadresse                              Physische Adresse   Typ
--------------------------------------------  -----------------  ---------
fda0:65da:e55a:1::1                           00-0c-29-56-69-f6  Abgelaufe 
fda0:65da:e55a:1::2                           00-0c-29-41-b8-97  Abgelaufe
fda0:65da:e55a:1::3                           00-0c-29-02-da-0b  Abgelaufe
fda0:65da:e55a:1:89f6:fad7:862a:c2e4          00-0c-29-41-b8-97  Abgelaufe
fda0:65da:e55a:1:e49b:4bb8:df52:d34a          00-0c-29-56-69-f6  Abgelaufe
fda0:65da:e55a:1:ecb9:2efb:ffa5:770b          00-0c-29-1a-a5-e4  Abgelaufe 
fe80::219:bbff:fe0e:c600                      00-19-bb-0e-c6-00  Abgelaufe (Stale) 
fe80::3aea:a7ff:fe6a:6b43                     38-ea-a7-6a-6b-43  Abgelaufe (^--this changes to Reachable when the ping is successful)
fe80::6651:6ff:fe27:6a8d                      64-51-06-27-6a-8d  Abgelaufe
fe80::6651:6ff:fe27:7ab0                      64-51-06-27-7a-b0  Abgelaufe
fe80::a248:1cff:fe6c:7a02                     a0-48-1c-6c-7a-02  Abgelaufe
fe80::a2d3:c1ff:feea:4359                     a0-d3-c1-ea-43-59  Abgelaufe
fe80::fe15:b4ff:fe2c:d338                     fc-15-b4-2c-d3-38  Abgelaufe
fe80::fe15:b4ff:fe2c:e3f0                     fc-15-b4-2c-e3-f0  Abgelaufe
fe80::fe15:b4ff:fe2c:e3f5                     fc-15-b4-2c-e3-f5  Abgelaufe
fe80::fe15:b4ff:fe2c:e3f6                     fc-15-b4-2c-e3-f6  Abgelaufe
fe80::fe15:b4ff:fe2f:ff46                     fc-15-b4-2f-ff-46  Abgelaufe
fe80::fe15:b4ff:fe31:e7c6                     fc-15-b4-31-e7-c6  Abgelaufe
ff02::1                                       33-33-00-00-00-01  Permanent
....
```

The host is my default gateway. It is a HP5406. I have configured two VLAN's
for IPv6. This is the default VLAN, which I am in.

```
SW5406-1# show ipv6

 Internet (IPv6) Service

  IPv6 Routing    : Enabled
  ND DAD          : Enabled
  DAD Attempts    : 3

                                                                       VLAN Interfaces

  Interface Name  : DEFAULT_VLAN
  IPv6 Status     : Enabled
  Layer 3 Status  : Enabled

  Address    |                                             Address
  Origin     | IPv6 Address/Prefix Length                  Status
  ---------- + ------------------------------------------- -----------
  manual     | fda0:65da:e55a:1::feed:1/64                 preferred
  autoconfig | fe80::219:bbff:fe0e:c600/64                 preferred

  Interface Name  : Firewall
  IPv6 Status     : Disabled
  Layer 3 Status  : Enabled

  Interface Name  : RFID
  IPv6 Status     : Disabled
  Layer 3 Status  : Enabled

  Interface Name  : Voice
  IPv6 Status     : Disabled
  Layer 3 Status  : Enabled

  Interface Name  : DPC
  IPv6 Status     : Enabled
  Layer 3 Status  : Enabled

  Address    |                                             Address
  Origin     | IPv6 Address/Prefix Length                  Status
  ---------- + ------------------------------------------- -----------
  autoconfig | fe80::219:bbff:fe0e:c600/64                 preferred
```

Any hint could be useful for me.

Let me know if you need further information.